# Грамотное кэширование в NodeJS проекте

Tags: node.js, кэширование, redis, highload

Планируется highload-проект с использованием NodeJS, MySQL, Redis, NGINX.
За основу взят nodejs фреймворк express, и для работы с сокетами (может это и не хорошее решение) - socket.io. Проект представляет собой single page application, предполагается, что сокет-соединение будет открыто повсеместно. Будет большое количество страниц, которые являются статистично-информативными, и не щадят бд тяжелыми запросами.

Есть несколько вопросов о том, как построить кэширование данных, и где лучше применять Redis, а где использовать другие способы.

1. Например, есть запрос к БД, его результат мы можем сохранить в Redis в виде JSON, при следующих обращениях уже будем брать его из Redis и, когда необходимо - делать инвалидацию данного кэша. - Насколько правильно это? И стоит ли именно в JSON хранить данные?
2. Нам иногда нужна закэшированная страница не только в JSON, а кусок или целиком HTML. - Правильно ли хранить эти куски в Redis?
3. Есть идея реализовать session-storage в Redis, как это сделать правильно? например ключом будет id сессии, а значением - массив данных о клиенте. - Это правильно или нет? Как будет лучше?
4. В каких случаях стоит записывать кэш в файлы на диск?
5. Стоит ли вообще пихать все что выше описано в redis?

Я не имею опыта в highload, поэтому мне интересно все, что вы скажете, очень нужны грамотные советы в построении проекта на перечисленных компонентах. Может, есть какие-то рекомендации по работе с сокетами в highload, либо еще что-то, что касается основ такого проекта.

Признателен за ваши полезные советы, благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Например, есть запрос к БД, его результат мы можем сохранить в Redis в виде JSON, при следующих обращениях уже будем брать его из Redis и, когда необходимо - делать инвалидацию данного кэша. - Насколько правильно это?

На сто процентов, но своевременная инвалидация кэша - довольно большой челлендж.

> И стоит ли именно в JSON хранить данные?

Вообще меня несколько коробит сохранять данные строкой, но особого выбора нет, и вообще это не должно влиять ни на что.

> Нам иногда нужна закэшированная страница не только в JSON, а кусок или целиком HTML. - Правильно ли хранить эти куски в Redis?

Нет, у вас же SPA, весь рендеринг должен быть на клиенте.

> Есть идея реализовать session-storage в Redis, как это сделать правильно? например ключом будет id сессии, а значением - массив данных о клиенте. - Это правильно или нет? Как будет лучше?

Если сессия у вас считается за постоянное хранилище, то неправильно, потому что Redis не предназначен для постоянного хранения данных (хоть и умеет время от времени скидывать данные на диск). Вместо этого лучше организовать двухуровневое (или даже трехуровневое) хранилище из связки Redis - БД (In-Memory - Redis - БД в случае трехуровневой связки).

> В каких случаях стоит записывать кэш в файлы на диск?

Как правило, ни в каких, есть база данных. Туда можно скидывать результаты тяжелых запросов, чтобы все ноды их видели, но даже в этом случае я бы организовывал промежуточный Redis-слой.

> Стоит ли вообще пихать все что выше описано в redis?

Чем больше будет висеть в кэше, тем лучше, но время от времени посматривайте на количество съедаемой оперативной памяти.

> Может, есть какие-то рекомендации по работе с сокетами в highload, либо еще что-то, что касается основ такого проекта.

Помните про две вещи

- Проект обязан масштабироваться горизонтально, т.е. простым добавлением новых серверов. Из этого вытекает, что изменения на одном сервере должны быть видны для всех остальных (это достигается за счет использования одного Redis и БД)
- Существует такая штука, как dogpile effect, который означает кучу пользователей, одновременно запросивших один и тот же ресурс. В случае с вышеописанным трехуровневым хранилищем сто синхронно пришедших пользователей не обнаружат запись в кэше и ломанутся (все сто) к БД. В случае, если в БД 20 одновременных подключений, и каждый запрос занимает 30мс, то последний пользователь получит данные не раньше, чем через 150мс (это в идеальном случае, на самом деле там будет значительно б*о*льшее число), что очень нехорошо.

Comment: Спасибо за детальный ответ! По поводу пункта 2 - есть все же случаи, когда отдавать нужно не JSON, а HTML, это например если пользователь зашел на первую страницу сайта, а не совершил уже внутренний переход, или например гугло/яндекс ботам мы будем кормить HTML, а не JSON. И еще, по поводу session-storage, можете по подробнее истолковать реализацию? я считаю что здесь будет неслабая нагрузка т.к. туда будут частые обращения (сокетам нужна авторизация, бывают события чтото вроде session reload ...) ну + сама node будет что-то  туда писать/читать

Comment: @sanu0074 рендерингом занимается клиент. Можете поднять какой-нибудь phantomjs и делать перенаправление на него, но если ваш бэкенд занимается рендерингом, то там не о нагрузках надо думать. Про сессию - я не понимаю, что именно непонятно. Сессия держится сразу в трех местах, бэкенд достает из ближайшего, в котором она есть.